# Window does not resize for Mac version of universal app

Tags: ios, ipad, resize, mac-catalyst

I have an app that started out as an iPhone/iPad app and I added support for Mac. According to videos and documentation I've read online, one of the things you get for free is the ability to resize screens. It does, in fact, work that way when I build to MacOS from Xcode. However, when I upload the build to Testflight and run that version of the app, installed by Testflight, it doesn't resize. I should qualify that. I can drag a corner to switch it between portrait and landscape, but the size remains the same.

I'm not sure what to look for, especially since resizing works when I build from Xcode. Any suggestions?

I'm using SideMenu as the navigation controller for the app. The main view controller that instantiates Side Menu adds four view controllers as children. One of those is a portrait-only view controller.

Since it works as expected when I build from Xcode, anything I try will have to be archived and uploaded to Testflight. So any suggestions of likely things to try would be greatly appreciated.

I am NOT doing anything with windowScene size restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue apparently was that I had installed the iOS version on my Mac. I don't recall seeing the switch between macOS and iOS at the top of the Testflight app, so I don't know if the issue was a Testflight issue or my not toggling that switch because I didn't see it. Anyway, after uploading another build without SideMenu and wondering why it wasn't appearing on Testflight, I finally noticed that switch, toggled it to macOS, installed the old version with SideMenu, and it worked just fine.

So I guess the answer is to make sure you are installing the macOS version. The iOS version is not resizable.